# Solutions to Schrödinger's equation in 2D polar coordinates when the potential is zero

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, coordinate-systems, boundary-conditions

For Schrödinger’s equation, in polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$, when the potential in the Hamiltonian is $0$ (free particle), I think a solution is $r^{-1} e^{-i(kr - \omega t)}$. This radial wave is centered at the origin of coordinates.

Can another solution, for the above described Hamiltonian, also be a radial wave function (with amplitude, at any point, that is again the inverse of the distance from the wave’s center), but not centered at the origin of coordinates?

Comment: Have you tried substituting into the Schroedinger equation and checking if it works?

Comment: You can start from the solutions of the Klein-Gordon equation These involve  spherical Bessel functions.

Comment: The wave function, described in the first paragraph of the question, is an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian described in that paragraph. I think if we consider the second paragraph of the question as describing translation operators acting on that wave function, then, since translation operators commute with this Hamiltonian with 0 potential, then the translated wave function should still work and still be an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian

Comment: You haven't specified boundary conditions. Without them, there are solutions like e.g. $\sin(r\cos\theta)$ that are not centered at $r=0$. In fact, without the BCs even $\exp(r\cos\theta)$ is a solution of the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: @Ruslan I was actually thinking about the quantum double slit experiment and the mathematical form of how the sum of the two radial waves, from the two slits, solve Schrodinger’s equation. Each must have the same time evolution operator that is just exp^{iwt}. So, each must also be an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian. The slit screen creates the BCs that the waves each be radial, with center point at the slit.

Answer (score 1):

The radial solutions are Bessel functions and the angular part are waves. You start with the free Hamiltonian in polar coordinates,
\begin{equation} 
H \psi(r,\varphi) = - \left(\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \varphi^2} \right) \psi(r, \varphi) = E \psi(r, \varphi).
\end{equation}
As so often with these types of differential equations, we can make the Ansatz
\begin{equation} 
\phi(r, \varphi) = R(r) \Phi(\varphi).
\end{equation}
Inserting this into the differential equation and dividing by $R(r) \Phi(\varphi)$ yields
\begin{equation} 
- \frac{r^2}{R} \frac{d^2 R}{dr^2} - \frac{r}{R} \frac{dR}{dr} - Er^2 = \frac{1}{\Phi} \frac{d^2 \Phi}{d\varphi}.
\end{equation}
The left hand side depends only on $r$, while the right hand side only depends on $\varphi$, thus both sides must be constant. We call the constant $-A^2$. Then the angular differential equation reads,
\begin{equation} 
\frac{d^2 \Phi}{d\varphi^2} + A^2 \Phi = 0 
\end{equation}
which is easily solved by
\begin{equation} 
\Phi(\varphi) = C_1 e^{i A \varphi} + C_2 e^{-i A \varphi}. 
\end{equation}
Since $\Phi(0) = \Phi(2 \pi)$, we conclude that $A \in \mathbb{N}$. The radial part is then given by
\begin{equation} 
r^2 \frac{d^2R}{dr^2} + r \frac{dR}{dr} + (Er^2 - A^2) R = 0.
\end{equation}
After substituting $\tilde{r} =  \sqrt{E} r$, this becomes the Bessel differential equation and the solutions are the Bessel fuctions.

So to answer your question, yes there are more solutions given by the Bessel functions modulated by trig' functions. As usual, you can represent any smooth function by a sum of suitable Eigenfunctions. But I guess your question is if we can also find Eigenfunctions that are displaced from the origin. And there the answer is no as this would break the symmetry of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer. My motivation is the quantum double slit experiment, where a plane wave, with frequency w, travels in a direction orthogonal to the slit screen and is incident on that screen. Then from each slit point a radial wave emerges of the form (1/r)exp{-i(kr-wt), where r is measured from the slit point from which the wave emerges. The wave function is the sum of those two waves. If both are expressed in terms of the same polar coordinate system, then the wave function will not satisfy Schrodinger’s equation, in that coordinate system, I think. That is confusing me.

Comment: I see. I think the way out is that the Hamiltonian isn't actually the free Hamiltonian but has to contain the slits. Therefore the solution is exactly what you got already, a superposition of two spherical waves displaced by the width of the slits.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of the slits as boundary conditions, but I think you’re right.